# Where is the application dump created by Environment.FailFast() located on the disk?

Tags: c#, .net, event-log

I am trying to use Environment.FailFast() in my application. The MSDN documentation says that it creates an application dump during application termination.

> The FailFast method writes the message string to the Windows
>   Application event log, ***creates a dump of your application***, and then
>   terminates the current process. The message string is also included in
>   error reporting to Microsoft.

Can someone direct me to the location where the dump is created?

Comment: Did you check the Windows Event Log? It may include it in the event.

Comment: There are few useful links http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/clr/thread/060506fb-9bff-4085-82be-68220944f011

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I used the following code to reproduce the issue:

```
Environment.FailFast("Something bad happened");
```

You need to add the correct registry entries for it to place the dump in your desired location or you can read it to find the location. Here is the registry key:

[image]

which is

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting\LocalDumps

You can read more about other options in [Getting full user mode dumps automatically when your process crashes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2010/08/23/getting-full-user-mode-dumps-automatically-when-your-process-crashes.aspx).

Comment: You don't have to specify it, there is a [default value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wer/collecting-user-mode-dumps): `%LOCALAPPDATA%\CrashDumps`